# List<T> : Marshall By Value or Marshall By Reference

Tags: c#, .net

i have a collection of object. when i add some object on that collection. will it save that object itself or save its reference.

```
List<Student> myList;
Student std1 = new Student();
Student std2 = new Student();
myList.Add(std1);
myList.Add(std2);
```

myList will contain what?
duplicate copy of std1 and std2 or reference of these two objects?

and if this **List resides on some remote location** and i access it via wcf service. then i add objects in this list. what will happen. Those objects will be added by **MBV** or **MBR**?

actually i have List ok and i am adding object of Student in this list..

in last I said that suppose I have this List in some Program which is on other machine. I can access that program using WCF Service. get the reference of that Program through WCF Service. and then i call Program.myList.Add(student). now will a duplicate copy will be generated on that remote machine and will be added to myList or reference will be saved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a `List<Object>` and `Object` is a reference type, so your list will hold references to instances.

I am not sure what you mean about the last part, could you please elaborate.

Comment: actually i have List<Student> ok and i am adding object of Student in this list..

in last I said that suppose I have this List in some Program which is on other machine. I can access that program using WCF Service. get the reference of that Program through WCF Service. and then i call Program.myList.Add(student). now will a duplicate copy will be generated on that remote machine and will be added to myList or reference will be saved?

Comment: Doesn't WCF serialize objects and send them over?

Comment: Okay, is Student a class or a struct? If it is a class and thus a reference type, then your list will still hold references. If it is a struct you list will hold the values of the Student instances.

As for the marshalling issue: MarshalByRefObject gives you a proxy, and the framework will update the original. You are not holding an actual reference to the original. For serilization you get a copy and changes you make to this are not reflected in the original.

Answer (score 0):

Because the Object type is a reference type, the List in the example will store reference values to the objects allocated as Student objects on the managed heap.